# And literally admirable

Tags: knowledge, wordplay, cryptic-clues

These are my very first try on making cryptics after a very bad-formulated and inaccurately clued cryptic crossword, but are my very own attempts to pay tribute to those who have contributed *sooo* much. So, here you go!

(1)

> Dog primitively underestimated by online games! (5)

(2)

> Ultimate amazing rep generator (3)

Hint:

> [knowledge](/questions/tagged/knowledge) part is minor yet crucial

These are not the only ones that homage should be paid to, so I hope I could continue the series, provided this puzzle is welcomed by all of you!

Comment: can anyone please explain why this is downvoted? thanks!

Comment: edited to provide hint and in the hope that the downvoter can retrieve the +1 or provide feedback on -1-ing... thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to Omega Krypton for filling in the gaps in logic.

(1)

> [Rubio](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/30633/rubio) = **R** (which is the [dog's letter](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/115461/r-is-the-dog-s-letter)) + **u**nderestimated **b**y + [io](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.io) (.io is the internet domain of the British Indian Ocean Territory, used for online games).

(2)

> [GPR](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/4421/gentlepurplerain) = obtained by taking the last letters of "amazin**g** re**p** generato**r**".

Comment: both answer correct, well done! but the wordplay for 1 can cover all letters, i am sure. will award tick for the one who figured that out!

Comment: @hexomino may be rot13(.eh - bayvar tnzrf, ovb - cebsvyr)

Comment: @Ak19 Interesting, but where does the "primitively underestimated" come in?

Comment: @hexomino Sorry, no ideas on that part !

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rube

Comment: @LeppyR64 hexomino's answer already conjectures that it 'perhaps refers to a shortening of "rube"', but it's still not clear how it's supposed to work. I mean, you could kinda-sorta say that a rube is primitive, but that doesn't make "primitively underestimated" mean "remove the last letter from a word that kinda-sorta means primitive".

Comment: @Gareth I missed that. Reading too fast I suppose. Thanks.  Oh I didn't read the answer, just the comments .  Whoops.

Comment: @OmegaKrypton Are you a science class moderator?

Comment: @OmegaKrypton You're sure there's not, like, a word missing from (1)?  Say, between primitively and underestimated?

Comment: @OmegaKrypton Not sure what you want to do with this puzzle at this point. I don't think your construction is correct, let alone fair, I'm afraid.

Comment: this took so long, so i'm gonna spoil it and accept this answer once you edited it. a poor one, i admit, but just wanna get this done... rot13(uggcf://ratyvfu.fgnpxrkpunatr.pbz/dhrfgvbaf/115461/e-vf-gur-qbt-f-yrggre)

Comment: @OmegaKrypton I don't think I would ever have gotten that. Will edit now.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a better clue for 1 could be

> Dog primitively routinely underestimated by online games! (5)

Since

> Primitively clues ‘first’, and so primitively applies to “**r**outinely **u**nderestimated **b**y” yields RUB. Then the online games portion as explained by Gareth would yield IO, making a cleaner clue for RUBIO.

Comment: Hence my [earlier question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/84675/and-literally-admirable#comment245863_84677); it certainly seems like a word is missing. However, the trailing exclamation and the title tell us the  clue should be taken more, er, **literally**, which leaves us with a different problem entirely - how to get the first letter out of the first word.